# Using NotebookImport on specific groups?

Tags: front-end, import, notebooks, cells

I'm trying to read in all input cells in a notebook that are contained in  (or outside of) a specific group.

```
NotebookImport[nb, "Input" -> "InputText"]
```

gives the input text of all the input cells in the notebook, but I don't know how to filter out the input cells in a CellGroup with a specific title.

A motivating application would be trying to import the input cells in a documentation notebook from only the Basic Examples and Possible Issues sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NotebookImport` doesn't support it directly but you could import `"Input"|"ExampleSection"` and just split by style. You could but you can't because somehow `ExampleSection` style in those cells is put there twice:

```
Cell[
  TextData[{"Basic Examples",... }], 
  "ExampleSection", "ExampleSection",...
]
```

Which is not a problem but `NotebookImport` [doesn't support it (which is a bug imo).](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133891/5478)

So at the end we have to live with `NotebookGet` or `Import` and parse it:

```
Cases[
  NotebookGet[nb],
  {
     c : Cell[
       _?(! FreeQ[#, ("Basic Examples" | "Possible Issues")] &), 
       "ExampleSection", 
       ___
     ], 
     r___
  } :> (
    c[[1, 1, 1]] -> Cases[
      {r}, cell : Cell[_, "Input", ___] :> First @ FrontEndExecute[
         FrontEnd`ExportPacket[cell, "InputText"]], ∞]
  ),
  ∞
]
```

> ```
> {"Basic Examples" -> {"nb = CreateDocument[{TextCell[\"project \
> title\", \"Title\"], 
>
>       TextCell[\"first section\", \"Section\"], 
>
>       TextCell[\"details\", \"Subsection\"], 
>
>       ExpressionCell[Defer[2 + 2], \"Input\"], 
>
>       TextCell[\"second section\", \"Section\"], 
>
>       ExpressionCell[Defer[3 + 3], \"Input\"], 
>
>       ExpressionCell[Defer[1/0], \"Input\"]}, 
>
>      WindowMargins -> {{Automatic, 0}, {Automatic, 0}}, 
>
>      WindowSize -> {500, 600}];
>
>   NotebookEvaluate[nb, InsertResults -> True];", 
>    "NotebookImport[nb, _]", "NotebookImport[nb, _ -> \"Text\"]", 
>    "NotebookImport[nb, \"Input\"]", 
>    "NotebookImport[nb, \"Input\" -> \"InputText\"]", 
>    "NotebookImport[nb, \"Input\" -> \"InactiveExpression\"]", 
>    "NotebookImport[nb, \"Input\" | \"Output\", \"FlattenCellGroups\" -> \
> False]", "NotebookImport[nb, \"Input\" | \"Output\" -> \"InputText\", 
>
>    \"FlattenCellGroups\" -> False]"}, 
>  "Possible Issues" -> {"NotebookImport[Notebook[{Cell[\"2+\", \"Input\
> \"]}], 
>
>    \"Input\" -> \"HeldExpression\"]", "2+", "2+", 
>    "NotebookImport[Notebook[{Cell[\"Grid[{{1,2},{3,4}}]\", \
> \"Input\"]}], 
>
>    \"Input\" -> \"HeldExpression\"]", "InputForm[%]", 
>    "NotebookImport[Notebook[{Cell[\"Grid[{{1,2},{3,4}}]\", \
> \"Input\"]}], 
>
>    \"Input\" -> \"InputText\"]"}}
> ```

Comment: Shouldn't the double ExampleSection be a syntax error?

Comment: @M.R. It is redundant but correct: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStructureOfCells.html