# NotebookImport ignoring multiple style cells

Tags: functions, bugs, import, notebooks, cells

**Bug introduced in 11 or earlier and persisting through 12.1**

> [...] I have filed a report to the development team, raising the issue to them. [...]
>
> [CASE:3802659]

---

```
CellPrint[Cell["test", "Text"]]
CellPrint[Cell["test2", "Text", "MyStyle"]]
CellPrint[Cell["test3", "Text", "Text"]]
```

```
NotebookImport[EvaluationNotebook[], "Text"]
```

> ```
> {"test"}
> ```

[Since multiple style cells are officially supported](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStructureOfCells.html) I would consider it a bug. Or have I missed something?

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you want that to return all three cells?  This does work for that:

```
NotebookImport[EvaluationNotebook[], "Text" | {"Text", _}]
```

> ```
> {"test", "test2", "test3"}
> ```

One can also pull only specific combinations:

```
NotebookImport[EvaluationNotebook[], {"Text", "Text"}]
```

> ```
> {"test3"}
> ```

Notably this matches none of the examples:

```
NotebookImport[EvaluationNotebook[], {"Text"}]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

Comment: It won't catch `CellPrint[Cell["test3", {"Whatever", "Text"}]]` but it is a good direction and at the end `x__ /; ! FreeQ[{x}, "Text"]` works, the problem is we need it for each mentioned style as it can happen in general.