# Cells[] ignoring multiple style cells

Tags: bugs, front-end, notebooks, cells, documentation

**Bug introduced in V9 and fixed in V11**

Same story as in [NotebookImport ignoring multiple style cells](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133891/5478),

```
CellPrint @ Cell["test", "Section", "Program"]

Cells[CellStyle -> #] & /@ {"Section", "Program"}
```

[image]

This cell was only found by `"Section"` selector. I'd expect `"Program"` to work too.

And again, [multiple style cells are officially supported](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStructureOfCells.html) so I consider it bug.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] There seems to be an inconsistency between the documentation of the `Cell` function at that tutorial (TheStructureOfCells).
>
> In the documentation it says that only one cell style can be specified, but in the tutorial it says that multiple can be specified. [...]
>
> The engineer assigned to that case filed a developers report regarding the issue you were reporting. I will add to that existing developers report to point out this inconsistency in the documentation. Thank you for bringing this to our attention.