# NotebookImporting sections from documention notebook?

Tags: notebooks, cells

How can I use `NotebookImport` for grabbing "ExampleSection" cells?

```
nb = NotebookOpen["paclet:ref/RandomPrime"];
NotebookImport[nb, "ExampleSection"->"Text"]
(* {} *)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of reasons those cells have multiple styles, or rather a duplicated style:

[image]

`NotebookImport` has issues with such cells: [NotebookImport ignoring multiple style cells](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133891/5478)

So you can import them with:

```
NotebookImport[nb, {"ExampleSection", "ExampleSection"} -> "Text"]
```

[image]

But it contains string representation of boxes with the cell opener etc.

You can play around with `NotebookImport` but this seems to do the job:

```
(
  NotebookRead /@ Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "ExampleSection"]
)[[
  All, (*every cell*)
  1,   (*TextData*)
  1,   (*TextData arg is list*)
  3    (*our string is after the opener and a spacer*)
]]
```

> ```
> {"Basic Examples", "Scope", "Applications", "Properties & Relations", "Possible Issues"}
> ```

Though I did not test it on every page.